# IOS 4.2 database panel

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ios4, sqlite

I'm currently developping a webapp for iphone which use the local sqlite database introduced with html5.
Before the 4.2 update I could see some informations and delete my database via Settings -> 
Safari -> databases.
But now this panel is gone !

Without this panel , there is no way to delete a database (sqlite dont support DROP DATABASE).

How can i bring back this database panel or delete a local database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the database panel !
It seems there is a little bug with the Settings app.

If you can't see the database panel in Settings -> Safari, just kill the Settings app in multitask (double click on home button then hold any icon in the list)
and reopen it.